# Path.combine issue in visual studio

Tags: c#, version-control, visual-studio-2013

I was doing some Path.Combine stuff in a c# class and it was working previously. I've now moved my project to a tfs workspace and the codes broken in a couple of classes where I was using the Path.Combine method.

Here is the code that's breaking now :

```
    string rootPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    string filePath = Path.Combine(rootPath,@"..\..\AdminAccount\User.txt");
    private string[] getLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@filePath);
```

The error : The name 'Path' does not exist in the current context.

If someone could help me understand why this is happening so that I can prevent it from happening again.

A quick overview of my file paths so you can see exactly how I'm doing all these paths, although this may not be anything to do with the issue:

[image]

Comment: A quick overview of my file paths so you can see exactly how I'm doing all these paths, although this may not be anything to do with the issue : http://i.imgur.com/wBNh8sA.png

Comment: It sounds like you are not importing `System.IO`.  Do you have the line `using System.IO;` in your file?

Comment: @Grant Winney : Funnily enough when I've opened the same project it's giving the exact error as you have explained here in this comment. The filePath can't access it because it isn't static. I'm going to take a look at it and see if I can fix this. Also I am using System.Io at the start of the file etc. Let me mess about with this and I'll get back here. Thanks for all the help so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath,@"..\..\AdminAccount\User.txt");
```

Comment: alternatively add `using System.IO;` to the top of the file

Comment: I didn't have to use the full line as this answer states however a mixed fix some from Grant in the comments in the question. To fix this, I had to make both string filePath and rootPath static variables.